# Capicator voltage difference on a 1990’s CRT circuit board

Tags: capacitor

I have (4) 25v 10uf capicators to replace on a CRT circuit board. I have some new 65v 10uf caps on hand, will they work? Is 2.5 X the original voltage to High? The CRT is a low resolution game monitor from the early 90’s
Thanks for your input.

Comment: FYI now Kodi has an free emulator for every legacy game machine. Setup is a bit complicated tho, you can play any game from Atari, ][e etc with any simulated input

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem, however it's unusual for low value capacitors like to require replacement, even after 25  years.

Answer (score 0):

Sure they will work. Voltage rating of capacitors (any technology) is a maximum rating, not a recommended or minimum rating.

Different voltage rating exist only because for any giving voltage rating, for each technology, there's a typical maximum capacity/size. Going from 25V to 65V for the same cap will probably mean it will be larger.

Short answer: if it fits, you'll be fine.